# How to filter comma separated field with Laravel eloquent

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a column containing comma separated values. I want to know how to build the eloquent to filter a query.

**Example Table**

| id | name | some_values | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | London | 0,0,1,null,0 | online |
| 2 | Paris | null,null,null,null,null | online |
| 3 | Dublin | 0,null,null,null,null | online |
| 4 | Wien | 1,null,null,null,null | online |
| 5 | Madrid | 1,null,null,null,null | offline |

Example. A query should return all entries with status online and 1,x,x,x,x. How do I do that?

My thought was to work with a regular expression. but I have the feeling that this could lead to performance problems. The table should contain about 250.000 entries.

With Laravel Eloquent:
`->where('some_values', 'regexp', '1,[null|0|1],[null|0|1],[null|0|1],[null|0|1]')->get();`

And also my pattern has problems with the fields that contain a value null `null`. so `1,null,1,0,0` would not be recognized.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `where('some_value', 'like', '1,%')` ?

Comment: @lagbox Thank you. And if i try to fetch rows with the pattern `x,x,x,1,x`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: @Progman Thank you! that is a very useful reference. It helps me to rethink my existing structure. This would not completely answer the question, but it would make it obsolete.